# How to send a 'date' as a request parameter in an ajax call to a Controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, date

I need to send a date as a request parameter in an AJAX call. Problem is, that the selected date is in the format (mm/dd/yyyy) and it cannot be sent as it. I have tried using the encodeURIComponent(eventDate) which converts "/" into %2F but it didn't work either.

One solution is to convert the date into string (in javascript) and replace "/" with "-" and then parse the string but want to use it as the last solution if there is no other method.

Comment: "I have tried using the encodeURIComponent(eventDate) which converts "/" into %2F but it didn't work either." What about decoding the value on the server side? Also, what about timestamps?

Comment: URL encoding and decoding should work just fine. Are you having a problem decoding it on the server?

Comment: Show us how you are passing the data. If the date is currently in the string format you say it is, passing it to jQuery in a way that results in jQuery encoding it should work.

Comment: Is it a possibility to send a unix timestamp and then turn it back into a date (or keep the timestamp itself and work with that)? e.g. new Date('MM/DD/YYY').getTime().

Comment: Decoding didn't come into picture since the request could not hit the desired controller.

Comment: here is the URL : $.ajax({url : GlobalVars['app_url'] + '/validate/eventdate/' + selectedDate + '/eventid/32'

Comment: well... Is your app capable of handling the date that way? it seems kindof odd for you to be passing a date containing slashes in a url that uses slashes to make it seo friendly... I could see an htaccess rule that mods that url interacting with the date that contains slashes, causing it to be invalid.

Comment: that is the problem, I cannot send date with slashes and that is why I was encoding it.

Answer (score -1):

My solution to this has always been to use one of the standard formats YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS or YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS (the T literally being a T).

So if you just need a date YYYY-MM-SS then it's in a database-understood format. There are a couple of strftime implementations in JS that are quite good, you're going to have to convert it into a string at some point to send the request.